# How to definitely install virtualenvwrapper with Python3.5 on Mac OS Sierra?

Tags: macos, terminal, python-3.5, virtualenvwrapper

Well, looking around here there are tons of questions about how to correctly installing virtualenvwrapper on Mac. I really tried all of them but for no avail. I've noticed the previous questions don't have the configuration like my computer, so here it is:

1. Mac OS Sierra 10.12
2. [Python3.5.2](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/python-3.5.2-macosx10.6.pkg) installed from [python.org](https://www.python.org) installer for Mac OS
3. This installation puts Python3.5.2 in this path: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3`
4. I've run `python3 get-pip.py`command to install `pip` correctly, as I think
5. `sudo pip3 virtualenvwrapper` to be sure all settings will be done as they should
6. As [the documentation says](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file), edited `~/.bash_profile` with the code below:

   ```
   export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
   export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/projects
   source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
   ```

Then, whenever I open a new fresh Terminal, I got this:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper virtualenvwrapper.sh:
There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for 
 VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is set properly.
```

I've tried the fixes from others questions, to no avail:

1. set `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3` on virtualenvwrapper.sh
2. set `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python3)"` on virtualenvwrapper.sh
3. `ln -fs /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3`
4. `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3`

Well, looking forward to anyone with a configuration like mine to see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after a lot of effort, I've decided to install `pip` and `virtualenvwrapper` on Python 2.7 shipped in macOS Sierra.

After that, I wrote the lines below on `.bash_profile`. Maybe there's something redundant here but, it works.

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Documents/Projects/
ln -fs /Users/myusername/Library/Python/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
ln -fs /Users/myusername/Library/Python/2.7/bin/virtualenv /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

After that, I've installed Python 3.5.2 from python.org and created a new enviroment pointing to it and everything is working just fine.

```
mkvirtualenv --python=python3.5 env_name
```

Answer (score 10):

This is pretty old, but posting this because I came here from google and finally figured out the right paths.

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

You have to make sure to have the actual python executable. This can be found by just simply browsing in Finder through to /bin and seeing what is there.

Comment: This actually worked for me! Thanks a lot, was looking for answers since last night!

Comment: changed to 3.7 instead of 3.6