# virtualenvwrapper PATH issue

Tags: python, virtualenv, homebrew, virtualenvwrapper

I'm setting up a new machine (OSX 10.12.6) and trying to get my python environment setup. I have installed both 2 and 3 with brew. The solutions described in other questions don't seem to help.

.zshrc looks like this:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/projects
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages'

source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Error I'm getting when I open a new shell:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

The weird thing is that everything works fine - I can use mkvirtualenv just fine. But I don't want the error message and I don't get what is going on with my path? Please help!

I installed virtualenv and wrapper with pip and pip3

pip freeze:

```
pbr==3.1.1
six==1.10.0
stevedore==1.26.0
virtualenv==15.1.0
virtualenv-clone==0.2.6
virtualenvwrapper==4.8.1
```

$PATH:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: I answered a similar question just 2 hours ago: [How to check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105511/how-to-check-that-virtualenvwrapper-has-been-installed-for-virtualenvwrapper-pyt/46106073#46106073)

Comment: I definitely tried that, but still get an error, I guess I don't get how to install wrapper for that version of python? Don't my pip commands do it?

Comment: Also, it's a bit different on OSX.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER\_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105511/how-to-check-that-virtualenvwrapper-has-been-installed-for-virtualenvwrapper-pyt)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to definitely install virtualenvwrapper with Python3.5 on Mac OS Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732423/how-to-definitely-install-virtualenvwrapper-with-python3-5-on-mac-os-sierra)